# How to plot treatment means in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have generated a random [set of data](http://pastebin.com/hQnaQYgk) here, as I cannot post my own. It's not great data but it should illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Specifically, I have three treatments, the effects of which are being measured each year.  Each treatment is replicated 6 times each year.

I want to plot the effect of treatment on the Dependent variable (DV) with year (i.e. over the course of the study) using ggplot2

I have tried:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = factor(Year), y = DV, fill = factor(Grp))) + 
geom_boxplot()
```

Which works well for this random data I have generated, but for my actual data the size of the boxes are much more variable and the graph is very difficult to interpret.  What I wanted to do to simplify things, was to instead plot the treatment means with year (rather than using the boxes), and add standard errors to these treatment means. I also want to join up these treatment means with a straight line between each treatment's mean in each year. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to recalculate mean and sd values before plotting in new data frame. Another way would be to define own `stat_` function. Here is modified example from `stat_summary()` help page. This will calculate mean and confidence interval for each treatment in each year and plot it as `geom="pointrange"`. Lines are added with `stat_summary()` and `geom="line"`.

```
stat_sum_df <- function(fun, geom="crossbar", ...) {
      stat_summary(fun.data=fun, geom=geom, width=0.2, ...)
  }

ggplot(test, aes(x = factor(Year), y = DV, colour=Grp,group=Grp)) + 
  stat_sum_df("mean_cl_normal",geom="pointrange")+
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="line")
```

[image]

### Update

To get standard errors you have to make new function. I named it `stat_mean_sd()`. Now use this function inside `stat_summary()`.

```
stat_mean_sd<-function(x){
  cal.df<-data.frame(
    y=mean(x),
    ymin=mean(x)-sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)),
    ymax=mean(x)+sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
  return(cal.df)
}

ggplot(test, aes(x = factor(Year), y = DV, colour=Grp,group=Grp)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=stat_mean_sd,geom="pointrange")+
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="line")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to get Standard errors (+/-1SE) rather than confidence intervals?

Comment: Ah, set the geom to geom="errorbar".  It doesn't specify what these error bars represent though...